# Gravitationally redshifted black body radiation

Tags: general-relativity, thermal-radiation

I am a bit confused by this thing: in the Planck's formula for the black body emission there is the term $$\exp\left( \dfrac{h\nu}{k_BT} \right),$$ how would this term change if gravitational redshift were non-negligible? I think that also the temperature would be affected, since $k_BT$ is a form of energy, so the net effect on this term should be null.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The light is first emitted and then redshifted.

The redshifted frequencies are proportional to the original ones.

The result is still a blackbody spectrum, but of a colder body.

Comment: Maybe you should add that the Temperature in the formula is the temperature of the emitting black body, which stays constant. It is only the frequency that changes in a redshift.